# TLS 1.2 not enabled by default in Asp.Net 4.7

Tags: asp.net, azure-web-app-service, tls1.2

As I have read [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/tls),

> By default, .NET Framework 4.7 and later versions is configured to use TLS 1.2 and allows connections using TLS 1.1 or TLS 1.0

that in ASP.Net, TLS versions upto TLS 1.2 are enabled by default.

But when using a ASP.Net 4.7 code (C#) and getting the value of ServicePointManager.Securityprotocol, I can only see *Ssl3,Tls* and nothing else.

I wanted to avoid hardcoding the TLS versions. Is there any other way of achieving that ?

Comment: @Andrew Morton, I am running an Azure App Service on Windows NT 10.0

Comment: Is your System.Web httpRuntime targetFramework attribute set to 4.7?